# Give an auto-generated ID in consecutive SQL Queries as a column value for another table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two tables , namely : `tblEventService` and `tblEventItem` ..

Following are the columns of both :

[image: columns]

This is the method i am using to insert into the two tables as suggested by @M.Ali in the answer :

```
public int concurrentInsert(EventService eventServiceObj, EventItem eventItem)
        {
            string query = @" Declare @EventServiceID INT;

                            insert into tblEventService(ServiceDate,ServiceVenue,Status,CustomerRemarks,ServiceID,VendorID,EventID) 
                            values(@ServiceDate,@ServiceVenue,@Status,@CustomerRemarks,@ServiceID,@VendorID,@EventID);

                             SELECT @EventServiceID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();


                            INSERT INTO TableEventItem(EventServiceID,VendorItemID,Price,Quantity,CustomerRemarks)
                            VALUES (@EventServiceID , @VendorItemID , @Price,@Quantity,@CustomerRemarks)";

            List<SqlParameter> lstParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceDate", eventServiceObj.ServiceDate));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceVenue", eventServiceObj.ServiceVenue));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", eventServiceObj.Status));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerRemarks", eventServiceObj.CustomerRemarks));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceID", eventServiceObj.ServiceID));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorID", eventServiceObj.VendorID));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventID", eventServiceObj.EventID));

            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventServiceID", eventItem.EventServiceID));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorItemID", eventItem.VendorItemID));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@Price", eventItem.Price));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@Quantity", eventItem.Quantity));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerRemarks", eventItem.CustomerRemarks));
```

The query works fine when i checked it by putting values hard-coded . Now i have one problem :

**the autogenerated ID @EventServiceID should be provided in the insert method.. how do i give that in C# code ?**

This is the method in C# code i am using :

```
for (int i = 0; i < rptr.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                EventService eventService = new EventService();
                EventServiceLogic eventServiceLogic = new EventServiceLogic();

                eventService.ServiceID = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)rptr.Items[i].FindControl("hdnServiceID")).Value);
                eventService.VendorID = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)rptr.Items[i].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value);

                TextBox txtDate = (TextBox)rptr.Items[i].FindControl("txtServiceDate");
                DateTime eventDate = new DateTime();

                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out eventDate))
                {
                    eventService.ServiceDate = eventDate;
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(lnkBtnOrder, lnkBtnOrder.GetType(), "key", "alert('Invalid Date!Please enter in the format : Date-Month-Year')", true);
                    return;
                }

                eventService.ServiceVenue = txtVenueName.Text;
                eventService.CustomerRemarks = txtRemarks.Text;
                eventService.Status = "pending";
                eventService.EventID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMyEvents.SelectedValue);

                EventItem eventItem = new EventItem();

                eventItem.VendorItemID = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)rptr.Items[i].FindControl("hdnVendorItemID")).Value);
                eventItem.CustomerRemarks = eventService.CustomerRemarks = txtRemarks.Text;
                eventItem.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)rptr.Items[i].FindControl("txtQty")).Text);

    eventItem.EventServiceID = //this is auto-generated. how should i provide this value ?


                int registerServiceResult = eventServiceLogic.concurrentInsert(eventService,eventItem);

                if (registerServiceResult > 0)
                {
                    lblTotal.Text = "This Works!";  
                }
                else
                {
                    lblTotal.Text = "This Doesn't Work!";
                }
            }
```

Comment: is it sql server or mysql? this are two different products

Comment: I think it is sql-server .. As  it is provided within Visual Studio!

Comment: As a side note that has nothing to do with your question, please be careful of embedding sql code into your application.  Its not a good programming practice.  You can program the same sql code into a stored procedure (for sql-server or function for mysql).  This gives the benefit of being able to modify how the sql works without the need to recompile and rerelease an application. As well as taking advantage of optimization done by the sql engine.  Good luck to ya.

Comment: @KennethGarza: thank u for the advice.. But i am alrdy using a 3-tier architecture.. Where in the "data-access layer" has all my business logic and queries ... I am only calling these methods(which have queries) from my c# code and doing necessary operations!

Comment: thats awesome, sorry for any poor assumptions, i try to spread best programming practices as far and wide as I can. Enjoy!

Comment: @KennethGarza : thanks for the advice .. Might be helpful to others ! Carry on the good work (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google system function [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) and you would write your two inserts like this...

**Single row Insert**

```
Declare @EventServiceID INT;

insert into tblEventService(ServiceDate,ServiceVenue,Status,CustomerRemarks,ServiceID,VendorID,EventID) 
values(@ServiceDate,@ServiceVenue,@Status,@CustomerRemarks,@ServiceID,@VendorID,@EventID);

 SELECT @EventServiceID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();


INSERT INTO TableEventItem(EventServiceID , Col2 , Col3 , ....)
VALUES (@EventServiceID , @var2 , @var3 , ....)
```

**Multiple rows Insert**

If you are doing multiple inserts you would do something like....

```
Declare @EventSrvcID_Table TABLE
(EventServiceID INT,
 Col1 [Datatype],
 Col2 [Datatype]) ;

insert into tblEventService(ServiceDate,ServiceVenue,Status,CustomerRemarks,ServiceID,VendorID,EventID) 
OUTPUT inserted.EventServiceID , inserted.Col1 , inserted.Col2 
        INTO @EventSrvcID_Table(EventServiceID , Col2 , Col3)
values(@ServiceDate1,@ServiceVenue1,@Status1,@CustomerRemarks1,@ServiceID1,@VendorID1,@EventID1)
     ,(@ServiceDate2,@ServiceVenue2,@Status2,@CustomerRemarks2,@ServiceID2,@VendorID2,@EventID2);


INSERT INTO TableEventItem(EventServiceID , Col2 , Col3 , ....)
SELECT EventServiceID , Col2 , Col3
FROM @EventSrvcID_Table
```

Comment: how should i provide the auto-generated id from c# code ?? See my updated question please

Comment: Used 3 queries separately ..  Long way but worked for me where    1)Insert into tblEventService 2)`select TOP 1 * from tblEventService ORDER BY EventServiceID DESC` - this returns a DataTable 3)passing the EventServiceID returned in the datatable .. But when 2 users will insert into the table the TOP 1 will not return true value .. What way shoul i do this...?

Answer (score 0):

**What I needed :** An auto-generated id , which is created while inserting into one table and that id is to be used in as a column value in other table.

**Table Names:** 1)tblEventService (auto-generated id : `EventServiceID`) 2)tblEventItem

**What I Did:** Method for tblEventService :

```
public int Insert(EventService eventServiceObj)
        {
            string query = "insert into tblEventService(ServiceDate,ServiceVenue,Status,CustomerRemarks,ServiceID,VendorID,EventID) values(@ServiceDate,@ServiceVenue,@Status,@CustomerRemarks,@ServiceID,@VendorID,@EventID)";
            List<SqlParameter> lstParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceDate", eventServiceObj.ServiceDate));
            lstParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceVenue", eventServiceObj.ServiceVenue));
        ..... 
//similarly add other parameters too 

            DBUtility.ModifyData(query, lstParams); //this query is an Insert Query

            string query1 = "select EventServiceID from tblEventService where ServiceDate=@ServiceDate and ServiceVenue=@ServiceVenue and Status=@Status and CustomerRemarks=@CustomerRemarks and ServiceID=@ServiceID and VendorID=@VendorID and EventID = @EventID";  //this query selects the EventServiceID of the data inserted by the corressponding User . This will make sure to select correct data even if there are concurrent entries.

            List<SqlParameter> lstParams1 = new List<SqlParameter>();

            lstParams1.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceDate", eventServiceObj.ServiceDate));
            lstParams1.Add(new SqlParameter("@ServiceVenue", eventServiceObj.ServiceVenue));
           //similarly add other parameters too 

            DataTable dt = DBUtility.SelectData(query1, lstParams1);
            return Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["EventServiceID"]);
        } //this will return the autogenerated id which i require in the other table!
```

Hence, what is did was **Insert** and then **Select** !This worked for me..!One of the answers also worked as a `query` but i had problem giving that parameter in the other table!